# Subtract from a Rect many other rects

Tags: javascript

I found this awesome math opeartion file on Rectangles:

https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/90ea1ebd30156df9ef530c6a9a1b6ea7

And the docs for it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Geometry.jsm/Rect

They have this fucntion `subtract`. But it only subtracts 1 rect from another.

However my issue was I needed to create a function where I have one rectangle, and from that I need to subtract an array of other rectangles.

For instance if I did this:

```
subtractMulti(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), [new Rect(0, 0, 100, 10), new Rect(0, 5, 100, 10)]).toString()
```

It should give me a single rectangle of `new Rect(0, 15, 100, 85)`

However my attempt is failing, my result is:

```
 "Rect[0,10,100,90],Rect[0,15,100,85],Rect[0,0,100,5],Rect[0,15,100,85],Rect[0,15,100,85]"
```

Here is my attempt to write `subtractMulti`, I was wondering if you could help me fix it.

```
function subtractMulti(aTargetRect, aSubtractRectsArr) {
    // for use with Geometry.jsm
    // returns an array of rects after subtracting each rect in aSubtractRectsArr from aTargetRect

    var resultRects = [aTargetRect];

    var subRects = aSubtractRectsArr;

    // for each rect in resultRects... subtract each rect in subRects
    var noNewResults = false;
    while (!noNewResults) {
        console.error('starting while loop iteration');
        var tempResultRects = [];
        resultRects.forEach(function(resultRect) {
            subRects.forEach(function(subRect) {
                tempResultRects = tempResultRects.concat(resultRect.subtract(subRect));
            });
        });

        console.log('tempResultRects:', tempResultRects.toString());
        // remove duplicate rects from tempResultRects
        removeDuplicateRects(tempResultRects);
        // test if all the rects in tempResultRects match all those in resultRects (not order, just dimensions and position)
            var iterateWhileLoop = false;
            // test if all rects in tempResultRects are in resultRects
            for (var i=0; i<tempResultRects.length; i++) {
                var foundTempResultRectI = false;
                for (var j=0; j<resultRects.length; j++) {
                    if (resultRects[j].equals(tempResultRects[i])) {
                        // ok found tempResultRects[i] in resultRects, so its not new
                        foundTempResultRectI = true;
                        break; // break j loop
                    }
                }
                if (!foundTempResultRectI) {
                    // its a new rect, so lets go through `while` loop again
                    iterateWhileLoop = true;
                    break; // break i loop
                }
            }
            if (iterateWhileLoop) {
                resultRects = cloneArrOfRects(tempResultRects);
                continue; // skip the "test if all rects in resultRects are in tempResultRects"
            }
            // test if all rects in resultRects are in tempResultRects
            for (var i=0; i<resultRects.length; i++) {
                var foundResultRectI = false;
                for (var j=0; j<tempResultRects.length; j++) {
                    if (tempResultRects[j].equals(resultRects[i])) {
                        // ok found resultRects[i] in resultRects, so its not new
                        foundResultRectI = true;
                        break; // break j loop
                    }
                }
                if (!foundResultRectI) {
                    // its a new rect, so lets go through `while` loop again
                    iterateWhileLoop = true;
                    break; // break i loop
                }
            }

            resultRects = cloneArrOfRects(tempResultRects);
            if (iterateWhileLoop) {
                // resultRects = cloneArrOfRects(tempResultRects);
                // continue; // nothing to skip below so no need
            } else {
                noNewResults = true;
            }

                // if all match, then set `noNewResults = true`
                // else there were new results so set resultRects to tempResultRects (for future match testing) then run the `while` loop again
    }

    return resultRects;
}

function removeDuplicateRects(aRectsArr) {
    // returns a new array, whose contents is references to those rects in aRectsArr that are not dupes
    var resRects = [];
    aRectsArr.forEach(function(aRect, aRectI) {
        var aRectIsDupe = false;
        for (var i=0; i<resRects.length; i++) {
            if (aRect.equals(resRects[i])) {
                console.log('aRect at i:', aRectI, 'was a dupe so removed it. aRect was:', aRect.toString());
                aRectIsDupe = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!aRectIsDupe) {
            resRects.push(aRect);
        }
    });
    return resRects;
}

function cloneArrOfRects(aRectsArr) {
    // as doing aRectsArr.slice() does not clone each rect element inside
    var resRects = [];
    aRectsArr.forEach(function(aRect) {
        resRects.push(aRect.clone());
    });
    return resRects;
}

document.write(subtractMulti(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), [new Rect(0, 0, 100, 10), new Rect(0, 5, 100, 10)]).toString())
```

Here it is in a runnable snippet:

```js
///////////////////////////library
/* This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
 * License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
 * file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. */

this.EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ["Point", "Rect"];

/**
 * Simple Point class.
 *
 * Any method that takes an x and y may also take a point.
 */
this.Point = function Point(x, y) {
  this.set(x, y);
}

Point.prototype = {
  clone: function clone() {
    return new Point(this.x, this.y);
  },

  set: function set(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    return this;
  },

  equals: function equals(x, y) {
    return this.x == x && this.y == y;
  },

  toString: function toString() {
    return "(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")";
  },

  map: function map(f) {
    this.x = f.call(this, this.x);
    this.y = f.call(this, this.y);
    return this;
  },

  add: function add(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    return this;
  },

  subtract: function subtract(x, y) {
    this.x -= x;
    this.y -= y;
    return this;
  },

  scale: function scale(s) {
    this.x *= s;
    this.y *= s;
    return this;
  },

  isZero: function() {
    return this.x == 0 && this.y == 0;
  }
};

(function() {
  function takePointOrArgs(f) {
    return function(arg1, arg2) {
      if (arg2 === undefined)
        return f.call(this, arg1.x, arg1.y);
      else
        return f.call(this, arg1, arg2);
    };
  }

  for (let f of ['add', 'subtract', 'equals', 'set'])
    Point.prototype[f] = takePointOrArgs(Point.prototype[f]);
})();


/**
 * Rect is a simple data structure for representation of a rectangle supporting
 * many basic geometric operations.
 *
 * NOTE: Since its operations are closed, rectangles may be empty and will report
 * non-positive widths and heights in that case.
 */

this.Rect = function Rect(x, y, w, h) {
  this.left = x;
  this.top = y;
  this.right = x + w;
  this.bottom = y + h;
};

Rect.fromRect = function fromRect(r) {
  return new Rect(r.left, r.top, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top);
};

Rect.prototype = {
  get x() { return this.left; },
  get y() { return this.top; },
  get width() { return this.right - this.left; },
  get height() { return this.bottom - this.top; },
  set x(v) {
    let diff = this.left - v;
    this.left = v;
    this.right -= diff;
  },
  set y(v) {
    let diff = this.top - v;
    this.top = v;
    this.bottom -= diff;
  },
  set width(v) { this.right = this.left + v; },
  set height(v) { this.bottom = this.top + v; },

  isEmpty: function isEmpty() {
    return this.left >= this.right || this.top >= this.bottom;
  },

  setRect: function(x, y, w, h) {
    this.left = x;
    this.top = y;
    this.right = x+w;
    this.bottom = y+h;

    return this;
  },

  setBounds: function(l, t, r, b) {
    this.top = t;
    this.left = l;
    this.bottom = b;
    this.right = r;

    return this;
  },

  equals: function equals(other) {
    return other != null &&
            (this.isEmpty() && other.isEmpty() ||
            this.top == other.top &&
            this.left == other.left &&
            this.bottom == other.bottom &&
            this.right == other.right);
  },

  clone: function clone() {
    return new Rect(this.left, this.top, this.right - this.left, this.bottom - this.top);
  },

  center: function center() {
    if (this.isEmpty())
      throw "Empty rectangles do not have centers";
    return new Point(this.left + (this.right - this.left) / 2,
                          this.top + (this.bottom - this.top) / 2);
  },

  copyFrom: function(other) {
    this.top = other.top;
    this.left = other.left;
    this.bottom = other.bottom;
    this.right = other.right;

    return this;
  },

  translate: function(x, y) {
    this.left += x;
    this.right += x;
    this.top += y;
    this.bottom += y;

    return this;
  },

  toString: function() {
    return "[" + this.x + "," + this.y + "," + this.width + "," + this.height + "]";
  },

  /** return a new rect that is the union of that one and this one */
  union: function(other) {
    return this.clone().expandToContain(other);
  },

  contains: function(other) {
    if (other.isEmpty()) return true;
    if (this.isEmpty()) return false;

    return (other.left >= this.left &&
            other.right <= this.right &&
            other.top >= this.top &&
            other.bottom <= this.bottom);
  },

  intersect: function(other) {
    return this.clone().restrictTo(other);
  },

  intersects: function(other) {
    if (this.isEmpty() || other.isEmpty())
      return false;

    let x1 = Math.max(this.left, other.left);
    let x2 = Math.min(this.right, other.right);
    let y1 = Math.max(this.top, other.top);
    let y2 = Math.min(this.bottom, other.bottom);
    return x1 < x2 && y1 < y2;
  },

  /** Restrict area of this rectangle to the intersection of both rectangles. */
  restrictTo: function restrictTo(other) {
    if (this.isEmpty() || other.isEmpty())
      return this.setRect(0, 0, 0, 0);

    let x1 = Math.max(this.left, other.left);
    let x2 = Math.min(this.right, other.right);
    let y1 = Math.max(this.top, other.top);
    let y2 = Math.min(this.bottom, other.bottom);
    // If width or height is 0, the intersection was empty.
    return this.setRect(x1, y1, Math.max(0, x2 - x1), Math.max(0, y2 - y1));
  },

  /** Expand this rectangle to the union of both rectangles. */
  expandToContain: function expandToContain(other) {
    if (this.isEmpty()) return this.copyFrom(other);
    if (other.isEmpty()) return this;

    let l = Math.min(this.left, other.left);
    let r = Math.max(this.right, other.right);
    let t = Math.min(this.top, other.top);
    let b = Math.max(this.bottom, other.bottom);
    return this.setRect(l, t, r-l, b-t);
  },

  /**
   * Expands to the smallest rectangle that contains original rectangle and is bounded
   * by lines with integer coefficients.
   */
  expandToIntegers: function round() {
    this.left = Math.floor(this.left);
    this.top = Math.floor(this.top);
    this.right = Math.ceil(this.right);
    this.bottom = Math.ceil(this.bottom);
    return this;
  },

  scale: function scale(xscl, yscl) {
    this.left *= xscl;
    this.right *= xscl;
    this.top *= yscl;
    this.bottom *= yscl;
    return this;
  },

  map: function map(f) {
    this.left = f.call(this, this.left);
    this.top = f.call(this, this.top);
    this.right = f.call(this, this.right);
    this.bottom = f.call(this, this.bottom);
    return this;
  },

  /** Ensure this rectangle is inside the other, if possible. Preserves w, h. */
  translateInside: function translateInside(other) {
    let offsetX = (this.left <= other.left ? other.left - this.left :
                  (this.right > other.right ? other.right - this.right : 0));
    let offsetY = (this.top <= other.top ? other.top - this.top :
                  (this.bottom > other.bottom ? other.bottom - this.bottom : 0));
    return this.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
  },

  /** Subtract other area from this. Returns array of rects whose union is this-other. */
  subtract: function subtract(other) {
    let r = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    let result = [];
    other = other.intersect(this);
    if (other.isEmpty())
      return [this.clone()];

    // left strip
    r.setBounds(this.left, this.top, other.left, this.bottom);
    if (!r.isEmpty())
      result.push(r.clone());
    // inside strip
    r.setBounds(other.left, this.top, other.right, other.top);
    if (!r.isEmpty())
      result.push(r.clone());
    r.setBounds(other.left, other.bottom, other.right, this.bottom);
    if (!r.isEmpty())
      result.push(r.clone());
    // right strip
    r.setBounds(other.right, this.top, this.right, this.bottom);
    if (!r.isEmpty())
      result.push(r.clone());

    return result;
  },

  /**
   * Blends two rectangles together.
   * @param rect Rectangle to blend this one with
   * @param scalar Ratio from 0 (returns a clone of this rect) to 1 (clone of rect).
   * @return New blended rectangle.
   */
  blend: function blend(rect, scalar) {
    return new Rect(
      this.left   + (rect.left   - this.left  ) * scalar,
      this.top    + (rect.top    - this.top   ) * scalar,
      this.width  + (rect.width  - this.width ) * scalar,
      this.height + (rect.height - this.height) * scalar);
  },

  /**
   * Grows or shrinks the rectangle while keeping the center point.
   * Accepts single multipler, or separate for both axes.
   */
  inflate: function inflate(xscl, yscl) {
    let xAdj = (this.width * xscl - this.width) / 2;
    let s = (arguments.length > 1) ? yscl : xscl;
    let yAdj = (this.height * s - this.height) / 2;
    this.left -= xAdj;
    this.right += xAdj;
    this.top -= yAdj;
    this.bottom += yAdj;
    return this;
  }
};

/////////////////////////////




function subtractMulti(aTargetRect, aSubtractRectsArr) {
 // for use with Geometry.jsm
 // returns an array of rects after subtracting each rect in aSubtractRectsArr from aTargetRect
 
 var resultRects = [aTargetRect];
 
 var subRects = aSubtractRectsArr;
 
 // for each rect in resultRects... subtract each rect in subRects
 var noNewResults = false;
 while (!noNewResults) {
  console.error('starting while loop iteration');
  var tempResultRects = [];
  resultRects.forEach(function(resultRect) {
   subRects.forEach(function(subRect) {
    tempResultRects = tempResultRects.concat(resultRect.subtract(subRect));
   });
  });
  
  console.log('tempResultRects:', tempResultRects.toString());
  // remove duplicate rects from tempResultRects
  removeDuplicateRects(tempResultRects);
  // test if all the rects in tempResultRects match all those in resultRects (not order, just dimensions and position)
   var iterateWhileLoop = false;
   // test if all rects in tempResultRects are in resultRects
   for (var i=0; i<tempResultRects.length; i++) {
    var foundTempResultRectI = false;
    for (var j=0; j<resultRects.length; j++) {
     if (resultRects[j].equals(tempResultRects[i])) {
      // ok found tempResultRects[i] in resultRects, so its not new
      foundTempResultRectI = true;
      break; // break j loop
     }
    }
    if (!foundTempResultRectI) {
     // its a new rect, so lets go through `while` loop again
     iterateWhileLoop = true;
     break; // break i loop
    }
   }
   if (iterateWhileLoop) {
    resultRects = cloneArrOfRects(tempResultRects);
    continue; // skip the "test if all rects in resultRects are in tempResultRects"
   }
   // test if all rects in resultRects are in tempResultRects
   for (var i=0; i<resultRects.length; i++) {
    var foundResultRectI = false;
    for (var j=0; j<tempResultRects.length; j++) {
     if (tempResultRects[j].equals(resultRects[i])) {
      // ok found resultRects[i] in resultRects, so its not new
      foundResultRectI = true;
      break; // break j loop
     }
    }
    if (!foundResultRectI) {
     // its a new rect, so lets go through `while` loop again
     iterateWhileLoop = true;
     break; // break i loop
    }
   }
   
   resultRects = cloneArrOfRects(tempResultRects);
   if (iterateWhileLoop) {
    // resultRects = cloneArrOfRects(tempResultRects);
    // continue; // nothing to skip below so no need
   } else {
    noNewResults = true;
   }
   
    // if all match, then set `noNewResults = true`
    // else there were new results so set resultRects to tempResultRects (for future match testing) then run the `while` loop again
 }
 
 return resultRects;
}

function removeDuplicateRects(aRectsArr) {
 // returns a new array, whose contents is references to those rects in aRectsArr that are not dupes
 var resRects = [];
 aRectsArr.forEach(function(aRect, aRectI) {
  var aRectIsDupe = false;
  for (var i=0; i<resRects.length; i++) {
   if (aRect.equals(resRects[i])) {
    console.log('aRect at i:', aRectI, 'was a dupe so removed it. aRect was:', aRect.toString());
    aRectIsDupe = true;
    break;
   }
  }
  if (!aRectIsDupe) {
   resRects.push(aRect);
  }
 });
 return resRects;
}

function cloneArrOfRects(aRectsArr) {
 // as doing aRectsArr.slice() does not clone each rect element inside
 var resRects = [];
 aRectsArr.forEach(function(aRect) {
  resRects.push(aRect.clone());
 });
 return resRects;
}

document.write(subtractMulti(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), [new Rect(0, 0, 100, 10), new Rect(0, 5, 100, 10)]).toString())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am adding a new answer because even it is inspired by the old one, I thought this one deserve its own. So, I realized that I could only use the method getWantedParts without the rest, but I wasn't satisfied with the recursion which could cause problems on complex subtraction.

### New code :

```
function subtractMulti(aTargetRect, aSubtractRectsArr) {
    var keptParts = [aTargetRect];
    for (var i = 0; i < aSubtractRectsArr.length; i++) {
        var keptPartsPartial = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < keptParts.length; j++) {
            keptPartsPartial = keptPartsPartial.concat(keptParts[j].subtract(aSubtractRectsArr[i]));
        }
        keptParts = keptPartsPartial;
    }

    return keptParts;
}
```

### Speed tests (100000 executions) in ms :

```
T0:496
T1:1769
T2:223
T0:500
T1:2066
T2:218
```

T0 = My first version, T1 = Version of @jpopesculian, T2 = My latest version.

As you can see, this last one is twice faster than my first one which was already more than three times faster than the T1 one.

Comment: Wow this is truly awesome, I have to accept this answer. Thank you very very much! Because I accepted this one, may you please change defeintion of `T1` to indicate that its @jpop's solution. For others that come across this. :)

Comment: You are welcome ! I did the changes for `T1`. Do you need further explanations on how it works ?

Comment: Last thing, only drawback compared to @jpopesculian's version. If you try Test #4 (in my other answer), this version returns 4 rectangles and jpopesculian's one only 3. We could add a merging process after then that would check if two sides of different rectangles are glued with the same size and then merge them.

Comment: That is totally fine. I am using this in a screenshot editor addon. And if there is extra rects thats no problem. Here is a screencast of your algo (`T0` right now) in use :) its used when making selection. Not when drawing shapes. As in final screenshot only the exposed (cut out areas) will show - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLMxG2G53nI - the addon currently is released but doesnt have the editor which im working on right now. this is the release - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/ - thanks again so much!

Comment: Here is a demo of T2 algorithm, the one in this post - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQWoFg6J7KQ - I thought about it, and the merging algorithm would be bad if rects are next to each other. In my use case if we mreged the rects, then as I drag the selection around it will get lost into the other rect i moved it through haha. But thanks very much for that note on extra rect if they are next to each other and same height or same width.

Comment: Nope, I wouldn't happen. Because the merge wouldn't be done for the "selection" rectangles (the subtracted ones), but for "the big one" : the result. Unless I did not understand correctly how you implement it.

Comment: Ah you are absolutely correct! Wow that was stupid of me haha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109296/discussion-between-master-djon-and-noitidart).

Comment: Hey @masterdjon - I had an issue with perf on one of my algos I posted question, and thouht you might be interested :) - http://stackoverflow.com/q/36678335/1828637

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of subtractMulti function. First I do a union of all rectangles to subtract, then I subtract this unified rectangle of the target one. Also, I keep the parts that union virtually created (like in the case of two disjoint rectangles).

EDIT : Ok, it took me 45 minutes to fix it, but now you can subtract anything. I added the draw function of jpopesculian to show visually what it gives, but shall be removed.

EDIT 2 : Added intersect on "missing/wanted parts" to ensure it is in initial rectangle.

```
var zIndex = 0;
function draw(rect, color) {
    if (!color) {
        color = "#F00";
    }
    const element = document.createElement("div");
    element.style.cssText = `
        position: absolute;
        background: ${color};
        top: ${rect.y}px;
        left: ${rect.x}px;
        width: ${rect.width}px;
        height: ${rect.height}px;
    z-index: ${zIndex};
    `;
zIndex += 10;
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}


function subtractMulti(aTargetRect, aSubtractRectsArr) {
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
    var color = 0;
    var colorAdd = 40;
    draw(aTargetRect, 'rgb(' + color + ',' + color + ',' + color + ')');

    // for use with Geometry.jsm
    // returns an array of rects after subtracting each rect in aSubtractRectsArr from aTargetRect

    var subtractSumRect = aSubtractRectsArr[0];  
    var intersectRect = [];     
    color += colorAdd ;
    draw(aSubtractRectsArr[0], 'rgb(' + color + ',' + color + ',' + color + ')');

    for (var i = 1; i < aSubtractRectsArr.length; i++) {
        color += colorAdd ;
        draw(aSubtractRectsArr[i], 'rgb(' + color + ',' + color + ',' + color + ')');
        subtractSumRect = subtractSumRect.union(aSubtractRectsArr[i]);
    }

    //Get missing parts
    function getWantedRect(currentRect, i) {
        if (i >= aSubtractRectsArr.length) return currentRect.intersect(aTargetRect);

        var subtract = currentRect.subtract(aSubtractRectsArr[i]);
        var wanted = [];
        if (subtract) {
            for(var j = 0; j < subtract.length; j++) {
                if (subtract[j].isEmpty()) continue;

                wanted = wanted.concat(getWantedRect(subtract[j], i + 1));
            }
        }

        return wanted;
    }

    var wantedRect = getWantedRect(subtractSumRect, 0);

    color += colorAdd ;
    draw(subtractSumRect, 'rgb(' + color + ',' + color + ',' + color + ')');
    var finalRect = aTargetRect.subtract(subtractSumRect);
    finalRect = finalRect.concat(wantedRect);

    for (var i = 0; i < finalRect.length; i++) {
        color += colorAdd ;
        draw(finalRect[i], 'rgb(' + color + ',' + color + ',' + color + ')');
    }

    return finalRect;
}
```

TEST 1 : Result OK!
`subtractMulti(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), [new Rect(0, 0, 100, 10), new Rect(0, 5, 100, 10)])`

Test 2 : Result Better! (Case more explained below)
`subtractMulti(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 100), [new Rect(0, 0, 100, 10), new Rect(5, 5, 100, 10)])`

Test 3 : Disjoint rectangles to remove : Result perfect !
`subtractMulti(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), [new Rect(0, 0, 50, 10), new Rect(50, 20, 50, 10)])`

Test 4 : Removing rectangle going outside of initial one : Result now works with EDIT 2!
`subtractMulti(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 100), [new Rect(0, 0, 100, 10), new Rect(5, 5, 300, 10), new Rect(5, 5, 50, 10)])`

In your specific case, you will obtain one rectangle in the returned array, but it could be more than one as in :
subtractMulti(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 100), [new Rect(0, 0, 100, 10), new Rect(5, 5, 100, 10)])

This case happens when the subtracting rectangle doesn't fill either width or height.

### Final version without drawing rectangles

```
function subtractMulti(aTargetRect, aSubtractRectsArr) {
    // for use with Geometry.jsm
    // returns an array of rects after subtracting each rect in aSubtractRectsArr from aTargetRect

    var subtractSumRect = aSubtractRectsArr[0];  
    for (var i = 1; i < aSubtractRectsArr.length; i++) {
        subtractSumRect = subtractSumRect.union(aSubtractRectsArr[i]);
    }

    //Get missing parts
    function getWantedRect(currentRect, i) {
        if (i >= aSubtractRectsArr.length) return currentRect.intersect(aTargetRect);

        var subtract = currentRect.subtract(aSubtractRectsArr[i]);
        var wanted = [];
        if (subtract) {
            for(var j = 0; j < subtract.length; j++) {
                if (subtract[j].isEmpty()) continue;

                wanted = wanted.concat(getWantedRect(subtract[j], i + 1));
            }
        }

        return wanted;
    }
    var wantedRect = getWantedRect(subtractSumRect, 0);

    var finalRect = aTargetRect.subtract(subtractSumRect);

    return finalRect.concat(wantedRect);
}
```

Comment: You can't do a union of all the subtract rectangles. If they're disjoint the union will create a rectangle large enough to contain both of them which would then subtract more than wanted

Comment: This is really awesome, it's having some issues with self contained rects though like this: `subtractMulti(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), [new Rect(0, 0, 100, 10), new Rect(0, 5, 100, 10), new Rect(65, 65, 10, 10), new Rect(45, 45, 10, 10), new Rect(90, 90, 100, 100)])`, it should give this result: http://i.imgur.com/HS06hg9.png - thanks so much for your superior work! i really appreciate it!

Comment: I compared and both give the same result with the new test you brang in

Comment: The rectangle upper-right is not there. Though, from what you passed, it seems to be normal.

Comment: Last comparison : Executed 100000 times having same condition (no drawing and in the other case, defining methods once) :
- Mine : ~1s
- Other : ~ 204s

Comment: Oups, I forgot to remove the console.log from his version. New times.

I tested it in ms instead for 10000 times : - Mine : 94ms - Other : 191ms

Comment: Oups #2, I forgot to remove the console.log from his version and to remove cleaning page in mine. New times.

I tested it in ms instead for 10000 times : - Mine : 59ms - Other : 191ms

Comment: Thanks so much for all your work!! I want to accept both your solutions, so Ill up vote your comments and accept the other. Thanks so much!

Comment: Those perf tests are much much appreciated. I implemented your method in my screenshot tool. As soon as I release  it I'll let you know, your algo is working beautifully! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version. I basically do a repetetive subtract and merge. There's probably a much more efficient way to do this by doing the logic in points (subtracting on the basis of contains point and the intersection of lines) and then finding the optimum rectangles to fill the new shape, but that logic escapes me for right now.

```
"use strict";

Rect.prototype.subtractMulti = function(subtractionArr) {
    let targets = [this]
    for (let rect of subtractionArr) {
        // subtract rect from all targets
        let newTargets = []
        for (let target of targets) {
            newTargets = newTargets.concat(target.subtract(rect))
        }
        // merge together newTargets to get targets
        targets = Rect.mergeAll(newTargets)
    }
    return targets
}

/** 
* Merge with another rectangle
* Much like union except it doesn't allow for increase in bounds
* Returns Rect[], either a single element if merged or two if can't merge
*/
Rect.prototype.merge = function(otherRect) {
    const union = this.union(otherRect)
    const intersection = this.intersect(otherRect)
    if (union.size == (this.size + otherRect.size - intersection.size)) {
        return [union]
    }
    return [this.clone(), otherRect.clone()]
}

/**
* Merges all Rects of a Rect[]
* Return Rect[]
*/
Rect.mergeAll = function(rectArr) {
    const result = []
    while (rectArr.length > 0) {
        // remove first element to merge with rest
        let rect = rectArr.shift()
        // delete if empty rect
        if (rect.isEmpty()) {
            continue
        }
        // try to merge with other rects
        let merged = []
        for (let index in rectArr) {
            let otherRect = rectArr[index]
            merged = rect.merge(otherRect)
            // if successful merge then break
            if (merged.length == 1) {
                rectArr.splice(index, 1)
                break
            }
        }
        // if merged then add back to array to evaluate again
        // else put it into result array
        if (merged.length == 1) {
            rectArr.push(merged[0])
        } else {
            result.push(rect)
        }
    }
    return result
}

/**
* Returns true if empty
*/
Rect.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    return this.width <= 0 || this.height <= 0
}

/**
* Defines size property (w x h)
*/
Object.defineProperty(Rect.prototype, "size", {
    get: function() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) { 
            return 0 
        }
        return this.width * this.height;
    }
})

// Draw function to help test and visualize
function draw(rect, color) {
    if (!color) {
        color = "#F00"
    }
    const element = document.createElement("div")
    element.style.cssText = `
        position: absolute;
        background: ${color};
        top: ${rect.y}px;
        left: ${rect.x}px;
        width: ${rect.width}px;
        height: ${rect.height}px;
    `
    document.body.appendChild(element)
}

// Test function to run
function main() {
    const target = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100)
    const subtractionArr = [new Rect(0, 0, 100, 10), new Rect(0, 5, 100, 10)]
    const result = target.subtractMulti(subtractionArr)
    for (let rect of result) {
        console.log(rect)
        draw(rect)
    }
}

// do test function
main()
```

Comment: Your special merge method is not necessary in this case. Let's see why. If you have two squares positioned at the same location : a small and a big. If you subtract the big of the small, you won't get a negative square neither the opposite (big - small), you will obtain an empty space. So, in conclusion, if the unified rectangles to be subtracted goes over the one to subtract from, it doesn't matter.

Test it using my method with this launch line :
subtractMulti(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), [new Rect(0, 0, 100, 10), new Rect(5, 5, 200, 10)])

Comment: You're probably right. You could most likely change the merge code to just testing for equality. I still don't think Union of subtraction rects is right though

Comment: Wow this works amazing. The other one had some flaws. I want to accept his answer too but I can only accept one. :(